# Other than calling `waker.wake()` how can I make sure the Future will be polled again?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm looking into some more complex Rust projects and I noticed that a lot of them instead of using only async functions implement `Future` manually to get greater control of what happens.

The problem is that in the entire project, there is no call to `waker.wake()` whatsoever, so I have no idea how they make sure the future is polled again.

Let's say I want to poll an endless `Future` that always returns `Poll::Pending` but without calling `waker.wake()`. What are the other options?

Also, any resources on this topic and async rust are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You may need to provide the specific situations you mean. In general though only the *deepest* `Future` will actually use the waker, so if what you're looking at uses another `Future` type, it's probably there instead (and most likely be for I/O or timer or other primitive operation).

Comment: @kmdreko Hmm, okay, is it possible that the waker is called in the async state machines that the compiler generates? That would actually make a lot of sense.

Comment: Mmmmm `async` blocks/functions usually `.await` something, which would be a deeper `Future`.

Comment: Generally wakers are only called when a future is awaiting something outside of its own future graph. This includes I/O (both file and network), channels, timers, etc. If future A is awaiting future B, then future A doesn't need to be explicitly woken up; that implicitly happens when future B wakes up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`Waker`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/task/struct.Waker.html) provided by the [`Context`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/task/struct.Context.html) is the only way (in general) for a `Future` implementation to communicate to its executor - which is to indicate that the task associated with that waker should be polled again such that progress can be made.

Making use of the `Waker` yourself is not very common since it can only be used effectively by `Future`s that have a out-of-band method to know that a value or signal being waited on is ready. This is usually restricted to low-level I/O operations, timers, other triggers from the OS, and notifications from other tasks or threads. If you are making your own `Future` that relies on other `Future`s, you won't use the waker yourself and simply pass the context when polling the inner `Future`.

When you use an `async` block or function, the state-machine type that is built by the compiler will implement `Future` with a `poll` function that defers to the current `Future` being `.await`-ed by simply passing the context. So its only the lowest, deepest `Future` that would actually use the waker.

That all being said, there are no guarantees. Your `Future` may be `poll`-ed without calling the waker; this can happen if your task is using something like `select!` elsewhere which is managing multiple `Future`s in the same task. You may also call `.wake()` on your waker but the executor is totally free to ignore it, or it may be stuck, or shutting down, or whatever else. In the most likely case, things will work as you'd expect but edge cases always exist.

This section of the Asynchronous Programming in Rust looks relevant: [Under the Hood: Executing Futures and Tasks](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/02_execution/01_chapter.html). If you are looking for a non-runtime specific implementation that uses the waker (since those may be very complicated underneath), you can look at [`futures::channel::oneshot::Sender`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/channel/oneshot/struct.Sender.html).

As a side note, a `Future` that always returns `Poll::Pending` is already in the standard library - [`std::future::pending`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/fn.pending.html) - but of course, it doesn't call the waker (since why would it if it is only always going to be pending?).

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot! Will check out the resources.